# Express nodejs Marketing JSON Workflow

Tags: node.js, graph, express, workflow

I'm currently building an Express.js app for a marketing department.
So, they need a graph to display their workflows.

1) The marketing team provide the list of the strategy's steps (from step => to step) (=> is a transition)
This list is saved in a JSON format.

2) A button to show the offer graph / workflow.

The graph seems like the banner here : https://www.openerp.com/apps/marketing_campaign/
(sorry, I can't yet post images ...)

Is somebody know a good implementation with nodejs ?

Thanks in advance.
C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my happiness here : http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/home/jquery.html
This plugin is very complete for drawing graph / workflow / tree / ...